# Create a new select options from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array created from JSON, and I want to create new options in my select.
I do not have any errors, and I don't know what's wrong with my code.
In HTML I have:

```
<select class="currencyList">
</select>
```

And in JS:

```
var currencyList = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
      getCurrencies();
      createOptions();
    });

    function getCurrencies() {
      $.getJSON(
        "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
        function(response) {
          $.each(response[0].rates, function(i, item) {
            currencyList.push(item);
          });
        }
      );
    }

    function createOptions() {
      var option = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < currencyList.length; i++) {
        option += "<option value='" + currencyList[i].code + "'>" + currencyList[i].currency + "</option>";
      }
        $(".currencyList").append(option);
    }
```

I can access data in the array from the console.

Comment: getCurrencies() is asynchronous, so createOptions() is called immediately after getCurrencies(), which means currencyList more than likely will not be populated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know what's wrong with my code

That's because the `$.getJSON` is an **async** function.

Basically, you're invoking `createOptions` function before the `$.getJSON` **AJAX** call is done.

You need to attach `done` promise **callback** function.

```
function getCurrencies() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
    function(response) {
      $.each(response[0].rates, function(i, item) {
        currencyList.push(item);
      });
    }
  ).done(function(){
       createOptions();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getCurrencies` is an asynchronous call, so `currencyList` is still empty when `createOptions` is called.

Call `createOptions();` after `each`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getCurrencies();      
});

function getCurrencies() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
    function(response) {
      $.each(response[0].rates, function(i, item) {
        currencyList.push(item);
      });
      createOptions();//call here
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, now i understand my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Because the `$.getJSON` is async function, you should call `createOptions()` into it not into your document ready function:

```
function getCurrencies() {
      $.getJSON(
        "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
        function(response) {
          $.each(response[0].rates, function(i, item) {
            currencyList.push(item);
          });
          createOptions();
        }
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an AJAX Request and correctly build the `currencyList` upon the return of the call but you are calling `createOptions` before the AJAX call is done.

That is because the code will continue executing, calling `getCurrency` and `createOptions` right away.

You can call `createOptions` from the `getCurrency` success directly, similar to the below, passing the currency list into it:

```
function getCurrencies() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
    function(response) {
      var currencyList;

      $.each(response[0].rates, function(i, item) {
        currencyList.push(item);
      });

      createOptions(currencyList)
    }
  );
}

function createOptions(currencyList) {
  var option = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < currencyList.length; i++) {
    option += "<option value='" + currencyList[i].code + "'>" + currencyList[i].currency + "</option>";
  }
  $(".currencyList").append(option);
}
```

You can also just process the currency more directly as it comes in, similar to this:

```
function getCurrencies() {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/?format=json",
    createList
  );
}

function createList(response) {
  var $list = $(".currencyList");
  var option;

  $.each(response[0].rates, function(i) {
    option = "<option value='" + response[0].rates[i].code + "'>" + response[0].rates[i].currency + "</option>"

    $list.append(option);
  });
}
```